# Using Templates Safe Substitute Function in a Loop

Tags: python, string

I have this simple code:

```
  html_string = '''<html lang="en-US">
            '<head> 
                <title>My Python articles</title>
            </head>
            <body>'''
    for i in range(2):
        html_string += '''
                <p>
                    <span style="white-space: pre-line">$''' + str(i) + '''</span>
                </p>'''

    html_string += '''</body>
        </html>'''

    html_template = Template(html_string)

    output_dir = "./html/"
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'my_page.html')
    with io.open(output_path, 'w+', encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace') as html_output:
        for i in range(2):
            html_output.write(html_template.safe_substitute(i="Hallo"))
            html_output.truncate()
```

It looks like the `i` in the `html_output.write(html_template.safe_substitute(i="Hello"))` doesn't correspond to the `i` in the for loop and all I get is:

```
$0

$1

$0

$1
```

`$0` and `$1` need to exist only once and each of them have to be replaced with the word **Hello**. Later I'll be replacing `$0` and `$1` each with a different input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) for template strings have this to say about substitution identifiers:

> By default, "identifier" is restricted to any case-insensitive ASCII alphanumeric string (including underscores) that starts with an underscore or ASCII letter.

Identifiers like "$0" and "$1" don't satisfy this condition, because they start with an ASCII *digit*.

Inserting a letter between the "$" and the digit like this ought to work:

```
html_string = '''<html lang="en-US">
            '<head>
                <title>My Python articles</title>
            </head>
            <body>'''

# Make substitution identifiers like "$Ti"
for i in range(2):
    html_string += ''' 
            <p>
                <span style="white-space: pre-line">$T''' + str(i) + '''</span>
            </p>'''

html_string += '''</body>
    </html>'''

html_template = Template(html_string)

# Map identifiers to values
mapping = {'T' + str(i): 'Hello' for i in range(2)}

output_dir = "./html/"
output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'my_page.html')

with open(output_path, 'w+', encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace') as html_output:
    html_output.write(html_template.safe_substitute(mapping))
    html_output.truncate()
```